# Submenu de un Submenu-CSS y HTML

Tags: css3

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;

 /*Flex*/

 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

body {
 background: #e9e9e9;
}

header {
 background: #2c3e50;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 70px;

 /*Flex*/
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;

 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header .logo {
 color: white;
 font-size: 40px;

}

header .logo img {
 width: 50px;
 vertical-align: top;

}

header .logo a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}

header nav {
 width: 50%;
/*flex*/
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}

header nav a {
 background: #c0392b;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 20px;

 /* flex*/
 flex-grow: 1;
}

header nav a:hover {
 background: #e67e22;
}
/* Menu Header */
nav {
    max-width:1000px;
    width: 90%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}

nav > ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background: #c0392b;
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* Submenu */

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  background: #c0392b;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;

flex-grow: 1;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #e67e22;
}

/* Submenu-Submenu*/

nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  background: #c0392b;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;

flex-grow: 1;
}


nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Er tour- una nueva forma de vivir tu ciudad y tu entorno</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewpot" content="width=device-width, user-scable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximun-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"> 
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
  <header>
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="imagenes/logo_web.jpg" width="150" alt="">
    <a href="www.ertour.com">Er Tour</a>
   </div>

   <nav>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="Servicios en Sevilla.html">Servicios en Sevilla</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Rutas</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">San Fernando-Plaza de Velazquez</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Puerta de Jerez-Palacio de San Telmo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Rutas en Espacios Verdes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rutas en Jardines</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      <li><a href="Servicios fuera de Sevilla.html">Servicios Fuera de Sevilla</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Rutas en Espacios Verdes Naturales</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Buenas tardes a todos,

quiero poner un submenu dentro de un submenu principal, pero el inconveniente que tengo es que este último submenu no lo puedo visualizar en el navegador, aparece como oculto. ¿que puedo hacer?

El apartado que no puedo ver es el de Rutas que debe desglosar otro submenú.

Gracias por las aportaciones.

Comment: Podrias poner sea una imagen, o mas bien utilizar la herramienta para colocar el código ejecutable dentro de la misma pregunta.

Comment: Utilizas bootstrap o es tu propio estilo?

Comment: Es mi propio estilo con editor de texto css

Comment: Dentro de apartado Ruta debe aparecer otro submenu, pero no me aparece cuando lo abro en el navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo el código desde el depurador del explorador hay un detalle en el `height` en la lista donde se encuentra Rutas:

```
//aqui es donde el alto no te permite ver el siguiente submenu
<ul>//este es el segundo ul de tu codigo 
  <li>
    <a href="#">Rutas</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">San Fernando-Plaza de Velazquez</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Puerta de Jerez-Palacio de San Telmo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Rutas en Espacios Verdes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Rutas en Jardines</a></li>
</ul>
```

tu tienes declarado este css:

```
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

el segundo submenu si se muestra pero como el contenedor tiene un alto especifico no lo muestra yo pude verlo si le pongo al `height: 200%`

Comment: gracias me ha servido de mucha ayuda